# How do I find a flaw in this false proof that $7n = 0$ for all natural numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fake-proofs

This is my last homework problem and I've been looking at it for a while. I cannot nail down what is wrong with this proof even though its obvious it is wrong based on its conclusion. Here it is:

> Find the flaw in the following bogus proof by strong induction that
>   for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $7n = 0$.
>
> Let $P(n)$ denote the statement that $7n = 0$.
>
> Base case: Show $P(0)$ holds.
>
> Since $7 \cdot 0 = 0$, $P(0)$ holds.
>
> Inductive step: Assume $7·j = 0$ for all natural numbers $j$ where $0 \le j \le k$ (induction hypothesis). Show $P(k + 1)$: $7(k + 1) = 0$.
>
> Write $k + 1 = i + j$, where $i$ and $j$ are natural numbers less than $k + 1$.  Then, using the induction hypothesis, we get $7(k + 1) = 7(i + j) = 7i + 7j = 0 + 0 = 0$. So $P(k + 1)$ holds.
>
> Therefore by strong induction, $P(n)$ holds for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

So the base case is true and I would be surprised if that's where the issue is.

The inductive step is likely where the flaw is. I don't see anything wrong with the strong induction declaration and hypothesis though and the math adds up! I feel like its so obvious that I'm just jumping over it in my head.

Comment: Can you really always find natural numbers $i, j$ such that $0 \leq i, j \leq k$ and $i+j = k+1$?

Comment: Wouldn't you just have to find just one case wherein they do though?

Comment: No. The "proof" assumes that for any $k\geq 0$, there exist natural numbers $i, j$ such that $0\leq i, j\leq k$ and $i+j = k+1$

Comment: As a general rule: For fake induction proofs, find the smallest case where the conclusion does not hold, and then do each step in detail with the corresponding numbers inserted, so that it should proof that exact case. That way you will almost always quickly find the problem. In this case, the smallest failing case is $P(1)$, so the number to look at is $k+1=1$, that is, $k=0$.

Comment: @celtschk You should post that as an answer; I think it's more instructive than the current answers that just give the man a fish.

Comment: As a matter of English, you can disprove a false theorem (i.e. an untrue statement that is claimed to be a theorem) but not a false proof. The word you need is *refute*: a false proof (of a real or false theorem) may be refuted. A false theorem may also be refuted, by disproving it (though not by refuting a false proof of it).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 Aw, you beat me to that!

Comment: @JiK: I've now posted it as answer.

Comment: Back in high school I was taught that induction proofs should be based on P(1), since (depending on who you are talking to) 0 is not a natural number itself. Is that wrong?

Comment: @walen induction proofs should start from the 'first' case, whatever that is; if you're trying to prove a statement about all strictly positive integers, then yes you start at $1$. If you're trying to prove a statement about all non-negative integers, then you start at $0$. If you're trying to prove something about all graphs, you start with a graph with one vertex and no edges (or maybe the empty graph!). And so on; whatever makes sense for the statement being proved.

Answer (score 90):

The problem is here:

> Write $k + 1 = i + j$, where $i$ and $j$ are natural numbers less than $k + 1$.

If $k = 0$, then you are trying to write $1 = i+j$ where $i$ and $j$ are natural numbers less than $1$. The only option for $i$ and $j$ is $0$, but $0+0 \ne 1$.

Answer (score 46):

As a general rule: For fake induction proofs, find the smallest case where the conclusion does not hold, and then do each step in detail with the corresponding numbers inserted, so that it should proof that exact case. That way you will almost always quickly find the problem.

In this case, the smallest failing case is $P(1)$, as that claims $7\cdot 1=0$ which is clearly wrong.
Therefore the number to look at is $k+1=1$, that is, $k=0$.

So let's look at the inductive step, and insert $k=0$:

> Inductive step: Assume $7\cdot j=0$ for all natural numbers $j$ where $0\le j\le 0$ (induction hypothesis). Show $P(k+1): 7(k+1)=0$.

The only number with $0\le j\le 0$ is $j=0$, so the induction hypothesis is that $7\cdot 0=0$, which clearly is true.

> Write $0+1=i+j$, where $i$ and $j$ are natural numbers less than $k+1$.

The only natural number less than $1$ is $0$. Therefore we have to write $0+1 = 0+0$ … oops, that's not right! **Error found!**

Comment: This is the best answer to the actually posed question, how to find the error in an induction proof of an obviously false statement.   The only thing to add is that this method will find at least one problem with the inductive argument, but there could also be other problems that appear at larger values of n.

Comment: @zyx by the well-ordering principle there is a smallest such problematic number...

Comment: It's an interesting question whether all errors in the induction step can be found by examining a finite set of "problematic numbers" and whether this can be done effectively (given that the conclusion is false for all $n \geq N$ for a known $N$).   I am not sure if just considering larger and larger problematic numbers will catch everything.   @djechlin

Comment: @zyx you're asking whether a proof can contain an infinite number of errors? I mean each step could also use the fact that $n^2 > n$ for all $n \geq 0$, Then each step would have an error in it, and there would be an infinite number of errors. One could fix the error that $n^2 > n$ is false for $n > 0$ by replacing to the less obviously fallacious claim that $n^2 > n$ only when $n \geq 1$, so that each error would also have a fix that would leave an infinite number of errors.

Comment: @djechlin, the proof is finite, so has only a finite number of erroneous statements. I'm asking whether there is a form of the "problematic numbers" strategy that is guaranteed to uncover them all.  I suspect there is not unless you have some way of computing, for every step of the proof, infinitely many $n$ where the inductive argument requires that step to be true in order for the implication $n \to n+1$ to hold.

Comment: @zyx no, that would solve Hilbert's 10th problem. There is no procedure to decide whether a general statement of number theory is true.

Comment: What is needed is a reduction from Hilbert 10th (or any other undecidable problem) to the problem of identifying all errors in an induction proof with a conclusion known to be false for $n \geq N$ with given $N$.   My suspicion was based on the idea that such a reduction may exist.   @djechlin

Comment: @zyx: There are two possibilities for fake proofs: (a) The proof is wrong, but the statement "for all n" is still true (or just not proven to be wrong). (b) The statement "for all n" is wrong, which implies the proof must be wrong. In the second case there is a smallest n where A (n) is not true. In the first case obviously not.

Comment: @gnasher729, this comments discussion has been about the more subtle issue of whether ALL wrong statements in the A(n)-->A(n+1) portion of an induction argument (for A(n) that is eventually always false) can be detected by choosing particular values of $n$ and whether the process can be done algorithmically.  Your observation is irrelevant to that.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, the problem *is* in the base case — in particular, $P(0)$ isn't *enough* of a base case.

The inductive step for proving $P(n)$ depends on writing $n$ as a sum of two smaller natural numbers; you can do this when $n \geq 2$, but you can't do this when $n=1$.

If you have both $P(0)$ *and* $P(1)$ in the base case, that's enough to make the inductive step work.

(of course, you can't prove $P(1)$, so you *can't* prove the base case)

Comment: This is true but problematic for people learning induction for the first time. You're right that fixing the proof (if it were possible) would require a bigger base case. But the actual error (as in, problematic line in the proof) is in the step case (which has been pointed out several times).

Answer (score 11):

Hint: $1=1+0\neq 0+0$. Study $P(1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have to check induction proofs, you should apply the general case in order to prove the first step of the induction. In this particular situation you want to prove P(1): $7*1 = 0$.

> Write $k+1=i+j$, where $i$ and $j$ are natural numbers less than $k+1$.

In the first step, this means:

Write $1 = i+j$ where $i,j$ are natural numbers less than $1$.

This statement already shows where the problem is in the induction proof, because the only natural number less than 1 is 0, and 1 cannot be expressed as $0 + 0$.

Comment: This is good advice, but not always sufficient; it's possible to write a bogus inductive "proof" where the general case only fails after two or more steps. For a simple example, consider an attempted proof that all odd numbers greater than 1 are primes, with the base case "3 is prime" and the (obviously false) induction step "$n$ is prime $\implies$ $n+2$ is prime".